# select columns with conditions with priority

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to select details from a table according to the language present. That is, I have a primary language culture and and a Secondary Culture. I need to select rows that have matching rows for primary if any else I need to select matching rows for secondary culture. I have more than 5 different tables to join all will have the same conditions.

### My table

```
ID           int    
Name     nvarchar(50)   
MasterKey    tinyint    
Culture  nvarchar(50)
```

### Required Output

```
Name     Culture
-----    -------
@#@$      en-AR
```

### Query

```
  declare
    @Primary  nvarchar(20) = 'en-AR'
    ,@Secondary nvarchar(20) = 'en-US'
    SELECT 
       LangTable1.Name AS Name
       ,LangTable1.Culture AS Culture
    FROM
       LangTable1
    WHERE
       LangTable1.Culture=case WHEN LangTable1.Culture=@Primary THEN @Primary
    ELSE @Secondary
```

### result

```
Name       Culture
-----      -------

Minhaj     en-US
@#@$       en-AR
Nann       en-US
```

Comment: Pls do consider posting db schema and desired output and the business rule !

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Also, be a bit more specific - do you only want 1 language returned, or do you want to select rows for both languages you pass into the variables?

Comment: Nope i want to select only 1 language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other two ways to get that is using a `UNION`

The first query removes the values of the secondary language that are duplicates of values of the primary languages checking with an `EXIST`

```
DECLARE @primary nvarchar(20) = 'en-AR'
DECLARE @secondary nvarchar(20) = 'en-US'

SELECT Name, Culture
FROM   LangTable1
WHERE  Culture = @primary
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, Culture
FROM   LangTable1 a
WHERE  Culture = @secondary
  AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   LangTable1 b
                   WHERE  a.Name = b.Name
                     AND  b.Culture = @primary)
```

The second query removes the values of the secondary language that are duplicates of values of the primary languages using `EXCEPT`

```
DECLARE @primary nvarchar(20) = 'en-AR'
DECLARE @secondary nvarchar(20) = 'en-US'

SELECT Name, Culture
FROM   LangTable1
WHERE  Culture = @secondary
EXCEPT  
SELECT Name, @secondary
FROM   LangTable1
WHERE  Culture = @primary
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, Culture
FROM   LangTable1
WHERE  Culture = @primary
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if what you're asking for

```
if exists(select name, culture from LangTable1 where culture=@Primary)
  begin
  select name, culture from LangTable1 where culture=@Primary
  end
else
  begin
  select name, culture from LangTable1 where culture=@secondary
  else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This might give you what you want:

```
;with cte(Name, Culture, CultureRank) as
(
select t.Name, t.Culture, case when t.Culture = @primary then 1 when t.culture = @secondary then 2 else 3 end CultureRank
from LangTable1 t
) 

select c.Name, c.Culture
from cte c
where c.CultureRank < 3
and c.CultureRank = (select MIN(CultureRank) from cte c2 where c2.Name = c.Name)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b0e2/2/0)